# how to compare stored hashed password with plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a login, logout and register system and storing password as hashed. When logging in I am comparing stored password with entered password but it is giving true even when password entered is wrong.

```
app.post('/login', (req,res)=>{
    const user = users.find((u)=>{
        if(u.email === req.body.email){
            return u
        }
    })
    if(user){
        const hash = user.password
        const passwordEntered = req.body.password
        console.log([hash, passwordEntered])
        if(bcrypt.compare(passwordEntered, hash)){
            res.redirect('/loggedin')
        }else{
            res.redirect('/login')
        }
    }else{
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
})
```

Comment: Your `if` condition will always be true because according to the docs "_If [a callback] is not specified, a Promise is returned_" - that return value will always be seen as `true` - hence you're users will always be logged in.

Comment: Change your code to reflect what the docs say. This will help: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#to-check-a-password

Comment: Change `compare` to `compareSync` or use the `compare` function's callback parameter and check the match there. As Randy says, `compare` returns a promise which is an object that's always truthy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to you question, the `bcrypt.compare` function returns a Promise. Since it looks like you're not wanting to use promises here, the simplest solution is to just replace the asynchronous `compare` method with the synchronous `compareSync` method.

I have included an example below (I also altered the formatting slightly for legibility):

```js
app.post('/login', (req,res) => {
  // I used filter here as it's easier to understand
  const currentUser = users.filter(user => user.email === req.body.email);

  // I fliped the if-else here so we can avoid that ugly nested if
  if(!currentUser) {
    res.redirect('/register');
    return;
  };
  
  const hash = user.password;
  const passwordEntered = req.body.password;
  console.log([hash, passwordEntered]);
  
  if(bcrypt.compareSync(passwordEntered, hash)) { // <-- here's the change
    res.redirect('/loggedin')
    return;
  }
  
  // I removed the else here as it wasn't necessary
  res.redirect('/login')
});
```